Is it possible to make calculations (data manipulation) with an xarray coordinate?
I have an Xarray.Dataset with the coordinates 'range' and 'time'.
How can I access the values of coordinate named 'range' to add a static scalar like 200 for example?
# imports
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

time = pd.date_range("2006-02-21", freq="s", periods=4)
print(time)

# create a small xarray
da = xr.DataArray(np.random.randn(4, 4), dims=("range", "time"), coords={"time": time})

# add a coordinate to this array with shifts to apply to each rows
da=da.assign_coords(range=('range', [1.56,5.233,10.98,17.43]))
print(da)


The aimed result for 'range' should be this:
Coordinates:
  * range    (range) float64 201.56 205.233 210.98 217.43

This is not working:
da.range = da.range + 200


You are very close.
You will need to use assign_coords again to update the Xarray DataArray with the new range.
To perform a calculation, you need to access the array by using da.range.values.
Try this:
da = da.assign_coords(range = da.range.values + 200)
print(da)

<xarray.DataArray (range: 4, time: 4)>
array([[ 1.841789,  0.488786,  0.2098  , -0.653168],
       [-0.84231 , -0.972959, -1.077549, -0.310968],
       [-0.740298,  1.628546, -0.373804, -0.391335],
       [-0.564398, -1.487397,  2.735653,  0.019958]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2006-02-21 ... 2006-02-21T00:00:03
  * range    (range) float64 201.6 205.2 211.0 217.4


thank you for that hint! I wasn`t aware of that. It works very well now :-)
